# codeigniter Call to a member function is_admin() on a non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

I am getting this error when i try to login to my admin page where i ask it to verify the credentials

here are some snippets:

```
// Tank_Auth.php Line 71
$this->ci->session->set_userdata(array(
    'is_admin'  => (bool) $user->is_admin, // added
    'user_id'   => $user->id,
    'username'  => $user->username,
    'status'    => ($user->activated == 1) ? STATUS_ACTIVATED : STATUS_NOT_ACTIVATED,
));
function is_admin()
{
    return $this->logged_in() && $this->ci->session->userdata('is_admin') === TRUE;
}


// controllers/auth.php Line 30
function login()
{
    if ($this->tank_auth->is_admin()) {
        redirect('admin');
    } elseif ($this->tank_auth->is_logged_in()) {
        redirect('user');
    }
```

so i though if i added this to my login page it would verify that i am an admin:

```
public function index() {

   if ($this->tank_auth->is_admin())  {
        redirect('admin/dashboard');
    } else {
    $this->load->view('admin/vwLogin');
    }
}
```

Can anybody help me with this please? i am really lost now on how to solve this.

Comment: What's the line where you get the error? Is it this one: `is_admin'  => (bool) $user->is_admin`?

Comment: sorry that i didn't specify that properly but i got my error here: $this->tank_auth->is_admin()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In codeigniter,

before calling model (`tank_auth`: I assume that this is a model) , you need to load that file.

```
$this->load->model('tank_auth');
```

PS: your model file must be inside model folder. If you have one more folder inside that, then:

```
$this->load->model('/extra_folder_name/tank_auth');
```

Comment: Thank you it works now i think because i am getting this now: This webpage has a redirect loop this is my browser and not codeigniter so my guess is that it works